# Kafka consumer group describe command shows offset for some partitions as ' - '

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a topic with 50 partitions and a consumer group listening to this topic. I am using below command for looking at offsets

```
./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server <Broker_IP>:<Broker port> --describe --group <consumer-group name> | grep <topic name>
```

When i publish a message, lets say my current offset is 100. My application reads that message. But after some time of inactivity, when i use the same command, the current offset changes to '-' and after some more time when is use the same command, the details don't show up.

Can this potentially lead to message loss in kafka?

Answer (score 0):

This typically means the group is rebalancing and reading no data.

Whether you are losing data (i.e. not processing it) or reading duplicate messages depends on the settings of the consumer applications, such as `auto.reset.offset` and how frequently you are committing offsets, if at all.

Over time, the data in the topic might fall off based on the retention settings, in which case you would lose data as Kafka is deleting it.